# nth child in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jquery code.I need javascript code to select nth child.Is it possible to select nth child using javascript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".gl-testim-text p:nth-child(2)").click(function(){
          $(".gl-testim-text p:nth-child(3)").show();
       });
     });

 </script>
```

Comment: Have a look - https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/ and https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('p:nth-child(n)')`

Comment: @nikhil OP meant without jQuery

Comment: I think `$(this).next()` should help you!

Comment: @Rajesh - Thank you for clarification! I misinterpreted.

Comment: while using jquery,  jquery.min.js will overwrite my entire site code.

Comment: XY Problem: *"jquery.min.js will overwrite my entire site code"* - sounds like you should fix **that** problem rather than find obscure ways to rewrite your clean jquery.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As commented by @[abhitalks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1355315/abhitalks), you can use `querySelector()` plus `:nth-child()` selector

```js
var second = document.querySelector(".content a:nth-child(2)")
console.log(second)

var even = document.querySelectorAll(".content a:nth-child(2n)")
console.log(even)
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <a href="google.com">Google</a>
  <a href="Facebook.com">Facebook</a>
  <a href="StackOverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>
  <a href="YouTube.com">YouTube</a>
  <a href="Example.com">Example</a>
  <a>blabla</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Purely native and basic

```
var length =  document.body.childNodes.length;
var last_child_of_body = document.body.childNodes[length-1];
```

This is just an example for last child. You can use any parent instead of body for your purpose

Answer (score 2):

use `.next()` method.
You can also try children traversal methods.

Comment: Just FYI, OP is not looking for an answer without jQuery.

Comment: @Rajesh  OP's code is in jquery. I think he is confused among javascript and jquery.

Comment: If thats the case, the there is no need for the question as his code would work just fine. Isn't it?