# Get nth offspring by HTML tag in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to get the Nth `tag` belonging to a given element (`top`) **and** child of the  class `sub` in the following example:

```
<div id="top">
    <div class="dumb">
        <tag>Not counted</tag>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sub">
        <tag>El 1</tag>
        <tag>El 2</tag>
        <tag>El 3</tag>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sub">
        <tag>El 4</tag>
        <tag>El 5</tag>
        <tag>El 6</tag>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to get the Nth tag. Here is what I already try:

```
let el = document.getElementById('top');
let a = el.querySelectorAll(`tag`)[n];
```

It works, but include the first element which is not child of a `sub` element.

```
let a = el.querySelectorAll(`.sub > tag`)[n];
```

It works properly I would prefer a CSS selector to avoid loading an array in JS.

```
el.querySelector(`.sub > tag:nth-of-type(${n})`);
```

It works for `El 1`, `El 2` and `El 3` but not for the others (4,5...). I can't figure out why?

I already read many ressources, but none solve my problem:

- [Get the nth child of a div by pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129301/get-the-nth-child-of-a-div-by-pure-javascript)
- https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-get-nth-child-of-element
- [nth child in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528100/nth-child-in-javascript)

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/buw5a2Ld/)

Comment: `:nth-of-type()`  works relative to sibling elements. For example if you did `querySelectorAll('.sub > tag:nth-of-type(2)')` it will return the second `<tag>` among its siblings for each `.sub` group. So it will return 2 elements. You used `querySelector` instead so it will return only the first of those 2. As a side node you keep calling the index `n` but when you use it in an array it should be zero based while in css selector is 1 based

Comment: *"...avoid loading an array in JS"*: because of memory consumption concerns?

Comment: @DiegoD If I understand, I have no other options than using a JS array?

Comment: You already have a working solution (2); why don't you go with it? If the number of elements is relatively small then query all of them hardly makes a noticeable difference in performance. On the other hand, if you have control over the HTML you can restructure it so that `tag` elements become direct children of `#top`.

Comment: @trincot Yes, memory consumption concerns and elegance

Comment: yes I wasn't perfectly clear before about the actual concern.. I meant that `nth-of-type` can't be a solution because your `<tag>` elements span across different parents. I still think only the js strategy would be possible if you need to count those elements without considering the parents as they all belonged to a single set

Comment: I wouldn't worry about memory concerns. It will always be a **tiny** fraction of the memory that the DOM uses.